# moving PHP MySQL web app offline

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, offline-mode

I recently built a web application for my company, and now they want it to support an offline mode. To complicate things, my company is very concerned about security and does not want me to use Xampp or Mamp. The application handles sensitive data and they think these programs will somehow make the data visible to the outside world (although I'm entirely sure this would be the case).

Anyways, I'm looking for a way to allow my application to run offline, and to also support the following technologies: PHP, MySQL, jQuery. The most difficult part of this is I need to execute PHP code outside of the typical server environment.

Can anyone please give me some advice on how I could implement such a system, and any associated vulnerabilities that I may face in terms of security and data storage?

Answer (score 2):

There are some strange points in your question

> now they want it to support an offline mode

Well, that's easy enough - get familiar with [html5's offline features](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline)

> To complicate things, my company is very concerned about security and does not want me to use Xampp or Mamp

Have you deployed your web app on a desktop machine? Or do you mean you are forbidden to use a webserver?? Xampp/Mamp are development tools - your public facing applications should be on a machine configured specifically for that purpose with a webserver running apache/nginx/iis/PHP5.4-builtin/whatever you like.

> The most difficult part of this is I need to execute PHP code outside of the typical server environment.

How is your environment none-typical? Mike mentions php-gtk - but IMO you shouldn't go down that route unless you're requirements are "desktop app" + "absolutely must be written in php" - which is unclear from your question.

> any associated vulnerabilities that I may face in terms of security and data storage

Well, anything you put in local-storage on a client (browser) the user can access - just bear that in mind. Don't send sensitive data to what is, from your perspective, an insecure and pseudo-public location i.e. some user's browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're installing this for an individual user on their machine - your best bet is to install apache/php/mysql, and configure apache to reject connections from any remote IP address.

The environment should be basically identical to your current application, but with only 1 user in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run html/javascript, you will probably need to run this in a server/client environment because a browser isn't capable of running the php and the php app as a stand alone app needs something to parse the html/css/javascript ( it needs the browser for it's presentation view ).

Best course of action is to put the application onto a server that you control access to. Set the access controls to specific IP addresses only, or even better if you can run it off an intranet behind a firewall where no one outside the network would be able to get to it.

PHP can run on a desktop environment, but they key here is that it won't run the javascript/html you use to display. You could use php with a third party library like php-gtk to make a desktop app that doesn't need a server or browser, but php-gtk doesn't have the best support.

If the application needs to store data for other computers/users to access, then it needs to be on a network. If it doesn't need to do this you might consider using a different programming language geared toward desktop applications so you can keep it entirely offline ( such a java or .NET ).